# GKE K8s LoadBalancer Service Target Group

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a `type=LoadBalancer` Service for my `nginx-ingress-controller`. 
It is working just fine, but I just noticed that my `LoadBalancer` service created a target group for all the nodes in my cluster and, of course these other nodes would fail `healthcheck`.

**Questions:**

1. Is that an expected behavior ?
2. If not; How can I configure it to be targeting only a specific node-pool/instance-group ?

P.S.: I have tried adding the `ServiceNodeExclusion` annotation to the other nodes. And also without, for like 10mins or so, all the nodes are healthy then the other nodes turn unhealthy.

---

`Other nodes` -> means the nodes which does not have an nginx-ingress-controller

Comment: did you get an answer elsewhere?

Comment: @pkyeck Unfortunately not. I just assumed that this is the expected behavior, as because it is not so critical if those other nodes aren't accepting outside traffic.